# How to style jump links to a named anchor in the same page?

Tags: navigation

I have a long page with a list of anchors underneath a hero image.

Currently I have

```
  Seciton 1  Section 2  Section 3  Section 4
  ------------------------------------------
  |                 Content                |
```

I want the links to be subtle, but give the user a way to know that this will bring the user to the particular section.

The best solution I have come up with so far is a darker Jump To in front of the list

Jump To  Section 1  Section 2  ...

I am looking for other ideal implementations or particular icons that would give insight into the action performed by the link.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is have a combination of a partially fixed header along with color changing links.

As you scroll down, the section links come with you. When you get to a certain section, that section's link changes color.

You can see this in action at[Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com)